# List<T>.Any(); How to get index of matched item?

Tags: c#, list, generics, any

I am comparing Listview items with Generic List items with the `List<T>.Any()` method like this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in lstviewAddsheets.Items)
{
    if (InvalidSheets.Any(x => x != null && x.FilePath == itemRow.Tag.ToString()))
    {
        // Match found
    }
}
```

Please tell me, how to get the InvalidSheets list index which was matched with `itemRow.Tag.ToString()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there seems some debate about how much faster it would be to use `List.FindIndex()` instead of Linq to find the index, I wrote a test program.

This assumes that you only care about finding the index of the first matching item in a list. It doesn't handle multiple matching items.

Also note that this test is worst-case in that the matching item is at the very end of the list.

My results for an x86 release build (run on Windows 8 x64, quad core processor):

```
Calling Via FindIndex() 100 times took 00:00:00.9326057
Calling Via Linq 100 times took 00:00:04.0014677
Calling Via FindIndex() 100 times took 00:00:00.8994282
Calling Via Linq 100 times took 00:00:03.9179414
Calling Via FindIndex() 100 times took 00:00:00.8971618
Calling Via Linq 100 times took 00:00:03.9134804
Calling Via FindIndex() 100 times took 00:00:00.8963758
```

showing that `List.FindIndex()` is roughly four times faster than using Linq.

Here's the test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Test
    {
        public string FilePath;
    }

    class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            int count = 1000000;

            List<Test> list = new List<Test>(count);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                list.Add(new Test{ FilePath = i.ToString()});

            string target = (count-1).ToString();

            for (int trial = 0; trial < 4; ++trial)
            {
                Action viaFindIndex =
                (
                    () =>
                    {
                        int index = list.FindIndex(x => (x != null) && (x.FilePath == target));
                    }
                );

                Action viaLinq =
                (
                    () =>
                    {
                        int index = list.Select((x, i) => new { Item = x, Index = i })
                        .First(x => (x != null) && (x.Item.FilePath == target))
                        .Index;
                    }
                );

                viaFindIndex.TimeThis("Via FindIndex()", 100);
                viaLinq.TimeThis("Via Linq", 100);
            }
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }

    static class DemoUtil
    {
        public static void TimeThis(this Action action, string title, int count = 1)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                action();

            Console.WriteLine("Calling {0} {1} times took {2}", title, count, sw.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

So given that `List.FindIndex()` is both much faster AND much easier to read than using the Linq, I can see no reason to use Linq to solve this particular problem.

```
int index = list.FindIndex(x => (x != null) && (x.FilePath == target));
```

versus

```
int index = list.Select((x, i) => new { Item = x, Index = i })
            .First(x => (x != null) && (x.Item.FilePath == target))
            .Index;
```

The first version wins on all counts IMO.

Comment: I assume one reason is the anonymous type. In your test case you it needs to create 1000000-1 instances whereas the `FindIndex` does not need it. However, +1 for the test.

Comment: Yes, that would seem to be a likely candidate.

Comment: list.FindIndex worked perfect, Fast, simple & clean code Thanks.

Comment: It's a shame `FindIndex` isn't part of the `IList` interface.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this

```
 int index =   InvalidSheets.FindIndex(x => x != null && x.FilePath == itemRow.Tag.ToString());
```

if you want to get the object directly then do this

```
 var matchedObject = InvalidSheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x != null && x.FilePath == itemRow.Tag.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can get the index:

```
var index = InvalidSheets.Select((x, i) => new {Item = x, Index = i})
                         .First(x => x.Item != null && x.Item.FilePath == itemRow.Tag.ToString())
                         .Index;
```

However you might want to refactor this with `FirstOrDefault` like this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in lstviewAddsheets.Items)
{
    var sheet = InvalidSheets.Select((x, i) => new {Item = x, Index = i})
                             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item != null && x.Item.FilePath == itemRow.Tag.ToString());
    if (sheet != null)
    {
       var index = sheet.Index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good and extremely fast code. Thanks for to bring me on correct path.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
InvalidSheets.IndexOf(InvalidSheets.First(x => x != null && x.FilePath == itemRow.Tag.ToString()))
```

It will get index of first invalid sheet matching the predicate

Comment: +1 Yep. If you have a `List<>` then `List.IndexOf()` is much more efficient that using Linq.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: `IndexOf` takes `T` not a lambda. `T` must also override `Equals`. It's also not "much more efficient" but near to micro-optimization in most cases.

Comment: @TimSchmelter My mistake: I meant to comment the `FindIndex()` method.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I cannot believe that there is such a difference if both use the  same  collection. The (reduced) source for `List.FindIndex`: `for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
    if (match(this._items[i]))
        return i;
return -1;` and for `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`:


`foreach (TSource current in source)
    if (predicate(current))
        return current;
return default(TSource);`. Maybe your measurement was not optimal.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I wrote a timing test, which reveals that (assuming you just need to find a single index) using Linq is more than 8 times slower than using `List.FindIndex()`. I realise this makes little difference for small lists, but this is hardly a "micro-optimisation". Furthermore, using `List.FindIndex()` is far shorter and ore readable than using Linq. Therefore, I can see no reason to use Linq in the case that you only want to get the index.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I shall post my test code and the results. Then you can see what you think. However, note that  you can't just use `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()` as you suggest. You need to use `Select()` too.

Comment: I changed the test to use a class rather than ints for the items, and it's now closer (`List.FindIndex()` is now only 4 times faster)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I agree that you should use `FindIndex` if that's really all you want to know, however,  often you change your mind and if just for debugging purposes. 8 times slower is micro-optimization if we are talking about milliseconds. Also, imho it is more important to compare few reads on large lists instead of comparing 100000 accesses on small lists.

Comment: @TimSchmelter My test did compare few reads on large lists (which you presumably can now see, now I've posted the code). I do realise that these things are irrelevant to many (most?) cases, but I also believe that it's good to know about the performance characteristics. I work in the field of medical diagnostics, where we have LOTS of data, and these things actually do matter a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can project the index with the overload, therefore you need to select an anonymous type:

```
var invalids = InvalidSheets.Select((s, i) => { Sheet=s, Index=i })
    .Where(x => x.Sheet != null && x.Sheet.FilePath == itemRow.Tag.ToString()));
bool anyInvalid = invalids.Any(); // is any invalid
IEnumerable<int> indices = invalids.Select(x => x.Index);// if you need all indices
```